# cannot install run file javascript nodejs fedora 18 linux

Tags: linux, node.js

i have a server with fedora 18. i already try to download nodejs with this command line

```
wget "https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.2/node-v4.2.2-linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

then i install node-dev like this..

```
npm install -g node-dev
```

after that i create a folder and a file package.json :

```
{
    "name":"NoChat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "description":"Akiong Test Chat",
    "dependencise":{
        "socket.io":"latest",
        "express":"latest"
    },
    "author":"akiong-Ryobest"
}
```

and this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Nostra Chat</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body, div, p { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
        body { font-family: "Arial"; } 
        form { position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
        form textarea { width: 100%; height: 50px; padding: 10px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #bbb; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #fff; } 
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }         
        #main { 
            width: 85%; 
            margin: 10px; 
        } 
        #side { 
            width: 15%; 
            background: #fff; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; bottom: 75px; right: 0; 
            border: 1px solid #bbb; 
        } 
        #side .header { 
            background: #eee; 
            color: #333; 
            margin: 0; 
            padding: 5px 10px; 
            font-weight: bold; 
            position: relative; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb; 
        } 
        #side .header p { 
            width: 100%; 
        } 
        #side .header #logout { 
            text-align: right; 
            position: absolute; 
            right: 10px; 
            text-decoration: none; 
            color: #888; 
        } 
        #side .header #logout:hover { 
            color: #333; 
        } 
        #user-list { 
            list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; 
            padding: 5px 10px; 
        } 
        #user-list .current-user { font-weight: bold; } 
    </style> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="main"> 
        <ul id="messages"> 
            <!--<li class="my-message">Hi server</li>--> 
            <!--<li>Hello client</li>--> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 

    <div id="side"> 
        <p class="header">Online</p> 
        <ul id="user-list"> 
            <!--<li class="current-user">Fani</li>--> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 

    <form action=""> 
      <textarea name="messageText" autocomplete="off"></textarea> 
    </form>       
</body> 
</html>
```

this is server.js

```
var express = require('express'), 
    app = express(), 
    port = 3000 
    ; 

/** 
 * Meng-konfigurasi express untuk meng-look-up file html 
 * dari directory bernama "public" 
 */ 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

/** 
 * Pada saat browser me-request path "/" 
 * response dengan file bernama "index.html" 
 */ 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html'); 
}); 

/* 
 * Meng-konfigurasi express untuk listen pada 
 * port yang telah di tentukan 
 */ 
app.listen(port, function(){ 
    console.log('listening on *:' + port); 
});
```

then i try to run server.js with this command.

```
node-dev server.js
```

but i get this error..

```
[root@server NoChat]# node-dev server.js
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/NoChat/server.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:43:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[ERROR] 22:21:45 Error
```

what wrong with my step?

or any suggestion for me? i am trying to create a chatting with websocket...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

You do not have the module `express` installed. To install it, run `npm install express` in the command line (while in the same folder as the server.js file).